# Java GUI application?

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager

I'm building application in NetBeans 7.1, and I'm new in it. I have made one JFrame and two JPanel's, I want to switch between JPanel's on button click(I have buttons in those panels of course). The thing is I made those JFrame and JPanel's with NetBeans IDE and I don't have idea how to switch between JPanel's inside one JFrame. I tried with SetVisible(true); but that only opens new JFrame which I don't want.
Thank you all in advance.

Comment: You'll want to read the Swing tutorials. You can find them and all the Java tutorials here: [The Really Big Index](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reallybigindex.html). Search for the CardLayout tutorial on this page.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels thanks for that link, I never knew it existed :)

Comment: You can use JTabbedPane to switch between multiple panels.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to swap between panels in the frame, then you probably want a [JCardLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/CardLayout.html).

You would set the layout manager to JCardLayout of the frame, and then add the two panels to the frame. Then, when the button is pressed, you can use 'first(), last(), next(), previous() or show()` to move between the panels.

If you want your flipper button to be visible all the time, use some other layout on the frame, and put the button to the frame (in whatever appropriate fashion), and then create another panel with a card layout, add the two panels with controls to the card layout panel, and then add the card layout panel to the frame.